# How can I rearrange the columns of this matrix?

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix

Given a binary matrix in which every row and column contains exactly only one 1, I need to rearrange the matrix columnwise so that it will become an identity matrix. For example, given a binary matrix:

```
Binary = [ 0     1     0     0     0
           0     0     1     0     0
           1     0     0     0     0
           0     0     0     0     1
           0     0     0     1     0 ]
```

To get the identity matrix we rearrange the column as `2 3 1 5 4`.

How can we optimally rearrange the columns for any given arbitrary square binary matrix?

Comment: Is your question about how to figure out what order is required, or simply how to perform the reordering itself?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: about the order required to convert binary matrix to identity matrix efficiently

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very simple way to do this is to use the function [FIND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/find.html) like so:

```
[index,~] = find(Binary.');  %'# Transpose the matrix and find the row indices
                              %#   of the non-zero entries
```

And you can test that it work as follows:

```
>> Binary(:,index)

ans =

     1     0     0     0     0    %# Yup, that's an identity matrix alright!
     0     1     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     0     1
```

**OLD APPROACH:**

This isn't as compact or efficient as the above solution, but you could also transpose the matrix and use [SORTROWS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sortrows.html) to sort the columns (now transposed into the rows) and return the sort indices. This will actually sort values in ascending order, which will give you an anti-diagonal matrix, so you will want to flip the vector of indices using [FLIPUD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/flipud.html). Here's the code:

```
[~,index] = sortrows(Binary.');  %'# Transpose and sort the matrix
index = flipud(index);            %# Flip the index vector
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the matrix can be manipulated into an identity matrix, why don't you just create an identity matrix with the same dimensions?

```
identity_matrix=eye(length(Binary))
```

Comment: maybe because he needs the indices from this matrix to operate on another matrix...

Comment: @yoda: That was not specified in the question.